# Using diff() in R ignoring NA

Tags: r

I have a R DataFrame df with the following content:

```
Serial N         year         current
   B              10            14
   B              10            16
   B              11            10
   B              11            NA
   B              11            15
   C              12            11
   C              12             9
   C              12            13
   C              12            17
   .              .              .
```

I would like to find the difference between the each consecutive pair of current of the same serial N. This is code I wrote.But I am getting some strange results

```
library(data.table)
setDT(df)[,mydiff:=diff(df$current),by=Serial N]   
    print(length(df$current))
```

I get the following as outuput for that column is quite strange, I get this:

```
2 6  NA NA NA 2 6  NA NA NA
```

What I would like to have actually is :

```
Serial N         year         current      mydiff
   B              10            14         
   B              10            16         16-14=2
   B              11            10         10-16=-4
   B              11            NA            NA
   B              11            15         15-10=5
   C              12            11
   C              12             9         9-11=-2    
   C              12           -13        -13-9=-22
   C              12            17         17-(-13)=30
   .              .              .
```

Is diff the right thing to do that? if not, how can tackle this (especially without using loops)?

Answer (score 2):

By applying

```
aggregate(current ~ Serial.N ,df1, diff)
```

one obtains

```
  Serial.N current.1 current.2 current.3
1        B         2        -6         5
2        C        -2         4         4
```

which corresponds to

```
B:    16 - 14 =  2
      10 - 16 = -6
      15 - 10 =  5
C:     9 - 11 = -2
      13 -  9 =  4
      17 - 13 =  4
```

So the output of `diff()` combined with `aggregate()` seems to make sense to me. I may not have understood exactly why you expect the output that you describe.

---

**Edit**

If the third entry in `Serial N` C of `current` is -13 and not 13 (the data in the OP is contradictory) the result is

```
aggregate(current ~ Serial.N ,df1, diff)
#   Serial.N current.1 current.2 current.3
# 1        B         2        -6         5
# 2        C        -2       -22        30
```

which seems to be closer to the desired output.

---

**Edit 2**

To add a column `mydiff`to the data.frame that takes the difference between consecutive values of the same `Serial N` while ignoring `NA` values we could use

```
df1$mydiff <- with(df1, ave(current, Serial.N, 
                   FUN = function(x) c(NA, diff(na.omit(x)))))
```

This will lead to a warning ("...not a multiple of replacement length"), but the result will be close to the expected output:

```
#  Serial.N year current mydiff
#1        B   10      14     NA
#2        B   10      16      2
#3        B   11      10     -6
#4        B   11      NA      5
#5        B   11      15     NA
#6        C   12      11     NA
#7        C   12       9     -2
#8        C   12     -13    -22
#9        C   12      17     30
```

The values in the `mydiff` column are correct, but one of the `NA` values is missing (in row 4). That is because we cannot ignore the `NA`s and at the same time preserve them; at least not without a significant manipulation of the `data.frame`.

Hope this helps.

---

**data**

```
df1 <- structure(list(Serial.N = structure(c(1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 
        2L, 2L, 2L), .Label = c("B", "C"), class = "factor"), year = c(10L, 
        10L, 11L, 11L, 11L, 12L, 12L, 12L, 12L), current = c(14L, 16L, 
        10L, NA, 15L, 11L, 9L, -13L, 17L)), .Names = c("Serial.N", "year", 
        "current"), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, -9L))
```